# how to submit 3 forms with one submit button using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am creating an onlineshop and I have three forms( that use 2 different php files ).
First form - text based for the user to fill in the Title, Price & Description of the product
Second form- uploading an image for the new product
Third form - choosing a category (table) from the database to add the record to the given table

How will I do that using AJAX? 
new in php and AJAX please help me how to modify my code.

1st form

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <label for="title">Title: </label><input type="text" name="title"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="description">Desc: </label><input type="text" name="description"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="price">Price: </label><input type="text" name="price" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

insert.php(used by 1st form)

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '',"onlineshop");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $sql="INSERT INTO mens (title, description, price)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[price]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

2nd form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../cms/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../cms/scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function(){ 
        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading"/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview'
        }).submit();

    });
}); 
</script>

<style>

body
{
    font-family:arial;
} 

.preview
{
    width:160px;
    border:solid 2px #dedede;
    padding:10px;
} 

#preview
{
    color:#cc0000;
    font-size:10px
}

</style>
<body bgcolor="#ffdd55">    
<font face=Arial size=3 color="#880088">
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php' >
<small>Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" /></small>
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div>
```

3rd form

```
<?php 
    include_once 'dropdown.php'; 
?> 
<small>Choose category:</small>
<br>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <select name="Tables" id="ddTables" name="form3">
<?php 

    echo $tables;

?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="tableSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>

<!-- Submit 3 forms together-->
<script>
$('#form1_submit_button').click(function(){
    $('#form1 #imageform #form3').submit();
});
</script>
```

dropdown.php(used by 3rd form)

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'onlineshop';

    if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
        echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "No tables exist! \n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $tables = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {


   $tables .="<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>"; 

    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice function for that.(.post)

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Use .val to read form data

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is some reorganization of your code - rather than trying to post to three separate pages from 1, perhaps try either combining the steps into one, or definitively separating them into 3.

For example:

(Separating into 3):

Page one, you fill out basic information of the product, which gets submitted and inserted into the database, then you are brought to page/step 2 (via hidden POST'd fields containing specific "product ID" or something), where you choose a category from the database. When you submit from there, it is inserted into the database, and you are brought to page/step 3, where you upload an image.  After submitting this, you're done!

-Advantages: Smaller individual pages, easier to make adjustments to any one of them.

-Disadvantages: Difficult to change something that affects all 3 pages, and if the user has slow internet, can lead to it taking a long time to create a single product.

---

(Combining):

All information is entered on a single page - category selection, basic product info, and file upload.  Submitting that page will process ALL the information in one fell swoop.

-Advantages: Easier to make large changes, all info is loaded/submitted at once so you won't end up with partial of incomplete data in your databases.

-Disadvantages: Lots of information to fill out on one page, may make finding a single thing to change difficult with a large amount of code.

Comment: I am interested in doing the combining method below, that was the main idea. Can you help me doing that because I am kinda new?

Comment: What you'll basically want to do is gather all the form elements you know you need (text inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc) and put them onto a single page.  On the PHP page that handles those submissions, just go down the list of inputs you have, and make sure you process each one.

Comment: so shall i put all the different php files into one and then create ONE form which uses that php file? will it work or will it confuse everything ?

Comment: ONE form using ONE php file for submission is correct.  I would re-write a bit of the PHP rather than just copy/pasting it into a single document, just be to sure it's all proper.