# how to set the variable in a mysql statement into user selection from a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating an onlineshop. The user add the details of a new product using a text-based fields for Title,Price,Description but it chooses where to upload the product using a drop down list with all the tables from the database.

The problem is, how do I set his selection to be the statement in my insert.php file, in order for the uploading of a new file to depend on his selection??

insert.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '',"onlineshop");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    $sql="INSERT INTO **--SELECTION OF THE USER FROM DROPDOWN--** (title, description, price)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[price]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

dropdown.php

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'onlineshop';

    if (!mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
        echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "No tables exist! \n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $tables = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {


   $tables .="<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>"; 

    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

index.html (form for the dropdown list)

```
<?php 
    include_once 'dropdown.php'; 
?> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <select id = "form3" name="Tables" id="ddTables">
<?php 

    echo $tables;

?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="tableSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Please if anyone can suggest anything I will really aprrieciate this. I don't think is something too hard, but for me it is!

Thanks!

connect.php

```
<?php
// Try to connect to MySQL
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die('Sorry could not connect to database');
// Check connect and return error if failed
$use_db = mysql_select_db('onlineshop');

$create_db = "CREATE DATABASE onlineshop";
if(!$use_db) {
    echo mysql_error();
    mysql_query($create_db);
    mysql_select_db('onlineshop');
}

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE onlineshop";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Database my_db created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }

//main table
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE mens( '.


  'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, '.
   'title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, '.
   'description  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, '.
   'price   FLOAT NOT NULL, '.
   'image varchar(200),'.
   'image_small varchar(200),'.
   'primary key ( id ))';

//copy attributes of the main table
$sql2= 'CREATE TABLE women AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql3= 'CREATE TABLE kids AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql4= 'CREATE TABLE infants AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql5= 'CREATE TABLE baby_books AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql6= 'CREATE TABLE garden AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql7= 'CREATE TABLE comics AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql8= 'CREATE TABLE cooking AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql9= 'CREATE TABLE moviestv AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql10= 'CREATE TABLE music AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql11= 'CREATE TABLE games AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';



$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connect );
$retval2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connect);
$retval3 = mysql_query($sql3, $connect);
$retval4 = mysql_query($sql4, $connect);
$retval5 = mysql_query($sql5, $connect);
$retval6 = mysql_query($sql6, $connect);
$retval7 = mysql_query($sql7, $connect);
$retval8 = mysql_query($sql8, $connect);
$retval9 = mysql_query($sql9, $connect);
$retval10 = mysql_query($sql10, $connect);
$retval11 = mysql_query($sql11, $connect);

//this checks only for table1, check for all of them
if(! $retval)
{
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Tables created successfully\n";
?>
```

Comment: Where are you selecting rows for the table? i guess it's missing. you are selecting tables from database, not selecting rows from a single table.

Comment: can you show what to add pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested code that does as asked. It uses 'mysqli' as object. The code escapes input. and the tablename is validated (not any more).

Note: all form field names are assumed to be lowercase.

PHP 5.3.18, MySQL 5.5.16.

```
<?php session_start();

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test',"testmysql");

    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    // removed table validation check...
    // $validTableNames = array('my_table_1', 'my_table_2', 'another_table_3');
    $tablename = isset($_POST['tablename']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['tablename']) : '';

    // $tableNameOk = in_array($tablename, $validTableNames);
    // if (!$tableNameOk) {
    //     die('Error: Invalid table name:' . $tablename);
    // }

    $title       =  !empty($_POST['title'])       ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['title']) : null;
    $description =  !empty($_POST['description']) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description']) : null;
    $price       =  !empty($_POST['price'])       ? $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['price']) : null;


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$tablename}` (title, description, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    // We need to 'bind' the three input variables to the there '?' in the query.
    // 'sss' indicates that the parameters are 'strings'.
    // the order must match the order of the column names.

    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $title, $description, $price);
    $allOk = $stmt->execute();

    if (!$allOk)
    {
        die('Error: ' . $mysqli->error);
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: i believe the file you have sent me above works, but I also need to create a form that includes 3 forms together for adding a new product. Do you mind taking a look to see if you can help me brother?see here
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702927/how-to-submit-3-forms-with-one-submit-button-using-ajax)

Comment: added the sql statement for creating the tables, so if you please modify the code you have sent me as now you have everything

Comment: also, this is for dropdown.php or insert.php?because the form for adding the record is using the insert.php but the form to preview the tables in a dropdown list uses the dropdown.php

Comment: I answered your original question with some code that works, is tested and does what you asked. I think that you need to decide whether i should be rewarded for that or not. If you want to ask a **new** question that others can contribute to, then that is up to you. I do not think it is fair to change the original question that you asked. Especially, as the change is quite significant and a lot more work.

Comment: Oh, i see you have asked a new question. Good :-)

Comment: yea i did. the thing is that the code above is for the insert.php right? because when i replace my insert.php code with the one you wrote to me above, i get the error 'Error: Invalid table name: '

Comment: I also tried to change the code into : $validTableNames = array('women', 'kids', 'infants', 'baby_books', 'garden', 'comics', 'cooking', 'moviestv', 'music', 'games');  -- Where the names listed above is all the table names in my database

Comment: It is an 'example' of how to validate input. The problem is that if you do not validate the 'tablename' input properly then 'less than good' queries can happen to you. If you want a 'table name' validation system then, yes, it can be provided. But, it isn't easy. I just wanted to show you that **all** the raw input **needs** be validated. The important point is that using the script provided will stop a lot of 'nasty' things happening to your database.

Comment: i just need it to work for now, then improve the quality of the coding. will you be able to show me how or I am asking for too much?

Comment: I have no idea how i can assist you further currently. The code i provide is working and it is based on your code. Earlier, you agreed it worked as you asked. You seem to want a complete application and help writing it. I have no objections to that. However, this forum, 'StackOverflow', is not the place for that.

Comment: the thing is I am new in all this thats why i asked for any further assist with this . the code seems okay i just get this error with the 'Invalid Table Name', so i was wondering if you used 'test' data because you haven't seen my tables. thats why I edited this post to show you my table names

Comment: $validTableNames = array($_POST['women'], $_POST['kids'], $_POST['infants'] .....);  --  Like this?

Comment: Look, just remove that test for the tablename check. Your code will then work fine. The tablename is still 'escaped' so it will do one of two things, get very confused or do something sensible. It is still 'reasonably safe'. You **must** leave the 'escaping' of the strings in place.

Comment: did that, i get an error on the bind_param line --  Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: I have amended the code to remove the 'table validation' check.

Comment: I have run the supplied code. It works fine here. Sadly, i cannot do anything more. I have no idea what the faults with your current code are.

Comment: just one more question and i am awarding your answer as the correct one for my question. what does the blind_param does? and what is the "sss"?

Comment: The 'bind_param' statement links the '?' in the query with the actual values to be used when you execute the query. Here is a tutorial: **http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/**. And here is the PHP manual that explains exactly what it does: **http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php**

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain the 'bind param' statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the same as with your values: $_POST['Tables'].
But this code is very unsafe.
At least you should add mysqli_real_escape string around you $_POST values.

Preferably you use a prepaired statement and params:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ? (title, description, price) VALUES(?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['Tables'], $_POST[title], $_POST[description], $_POST[price]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: can you explain it further for me pls?

Answer (score 0):

you should not mention `table name` in your insert query,

**error for your code:**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO **--SELECTION OF THE USER FROM DROPDOWN--** (title, description, price)
VALUES('$_POST[title]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[price]')";
```

**try this:**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `tablename` (title, description, price)VALUES(?,?,?)";
```

Comment: the dropdown contains a list of ALL the tables in the database. The user enters the Title, Price, Description of the product and then selects from the dropdown where to upload the new product. I want the selection of the drop down list to be equal to where the item is going to upload into the database

Comment: frist of all, you should check query to type your `tablename`.

Comment: the thing is that I want the fields title,description and price to be inputted from the text fields used from a form before. So i believe i should use the $_POST